# Moderation in Repeated Measures Design, how to analyze?

Tags: interaction

I want to analyze whether the effect of an intervention on the level of depressive symptoms is moderated by a variable called TA (continuous variable). I will do repeated measures analyses in SPSS with depressive symptoms used as the dependent variable which is measured at 5 time points. I think the independent variable (between-subjects factor?) will be the intervention (4 groups). The moderator variable (M) will be measured at one point in time as the moderator (for the first analysis) and an additional analysis will be conducted with the mean of all measures of TA (TOTAL = 4 points in time). Is this correct? And does somebody knows how to analyze in SPSS (model? factors? levels?). Thank you!

Comment: Why not use all observations of TA (instead of averaging). It sounds like you want to use a mixed effects model (equivalent to a repeated measures ANCOVA). See https://csass.ucsc.edu/self-study%20courses/SPSSMixed.pdf for further information.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think because then I have to do 4 different analyses?

Comment: You could allow TA to vary over time - using the corresponding measurement for each time point.